# ES6 Nested Grouping with Sum

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array like this:

```
[{
   id: 1,
   amount: 10,
   date: '21/01/2017'
},{
   id: 1,
   amount: 10,
   date: '21/01/2017'
},{
   id: 1,
   amount: 30,
   date: '22/01/2017'
},{
   id: 2,
   amount: 10,
   date: '21/01/2017'
},]
```

And I would like this to output like:

```
{
  '21/01/2017': {
    1: {
      amount: 20
    },
    2: {
      amount: 10
    }
  },
  '22/01/2017': {
    1: {
      amount: 30
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially grouping by data, nested grouping by id, whilst summing the relevant amounts.

So far I have tried using reduce, and have looked at lodash functions but have been unsuccessful. Reduce makes it easy to group by and sum by one prop, but I cannot find an elegant way to create the second level. I have created the a sandbox to demonstrate:

https://codesandbox.io/s/woj9xz6nq5

```js
const dataToConsolidate = [{
  id: 1,
  amount: 10,
  date: '21/01/2017'
}, {
  id: 1,
  amount: 10,
  date: '21/01/2017'
}, {
  id: 1,
  amount: 30,
  date: '22/01/2017'
}, {
  id: 2,
  amount: 10,
  date: '21/01/2017'
},]

export const consolidate = (data) => {
  const result = data.reduce(function (res, obj) {

    (!(obj.date in res)) ?
      res.__array.push(res[obj.date] = obj) :
      res[obj.date].amount += obj.amount;

    return res;
  }, { __array: [] });

  return result;
};

console.log(consolidate(dataToConsolidate))
```

Comment: why is the result in an array?

Comment: Mistake on my part, updated question.

Comment: What about `input.reduce(function(a,b) { a[b.date]=a[b.date]||{}; a[b.date][b.id]=a[b.date][b.id]||{'amount':0}; a[b.date][b.id].amount += b.amount; return a; },{});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a relatively ES6-y solution using `reduce`:

```js
const initial = [{ id: 1, amount: 10, date: '21/01/2017' }, { id: 1, amount: 10, date: '21/01/2017' }, { id: 1, amount: 30, date: '22/01/2017' }, { id: 2, amount: 10, date: '21/01/2017' }];

const parse = obj => obj.reduce((final, { date, id, amount }) => {
  let group = final[date] = final[date] || {};
  group[id] = group[id] || { amount: 0 };
  group[id].amount += amount;
  return final;
}, {});

const final = parse(initial);
console.log(final);
```

You'll want to add appropriate logic to handle missing/erroneous `date`, `id`, or `amount` keys.

Answer (score 5):

You could take the object as hash table and add the properties with a default style.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, amount: 10, date: '21/01/2017' }, { id: 1, amount: 10, date: '21/01/2017' }, { id: 1, amount: 30, date: '22/01/2017' }, { id: 2, amount: 10, date: '21/01/2017' }],
    result = {};

array.forEach(function (o) {
    result[o.date] = result[o.date] || {};
    result[o.date][o.id] = result[o.date][o.id] || { amount: 0 };
    result[o.date][o.id].amount += o.amount;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Really neat trick with that line of CSS, will be using this from now on

Answer (score 3):

As a fan of the library [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors), I might well use it to make everything a bit more explicit:

```js
const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, pluck, sum} = R

const data = [
  {"amount": 10, "date": "21/01/2017", "id": 1}, 
  {"amount": 10, "date": "21/01/2017", "id": 1}, 
  {"amount": 30, "date": "22/01/2017", "id": 1}, 
  {"amount": 10, "date": "21/01/2017", "id": 2}
]

const consolidate = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('date')),
  map(groupBy(prop('id'))),
  map(map(pluck('amount'))),
  map(map(sum))
)

console.log(consolidate(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Of course using a library just to solve this problem is simply overkill, when something like the solution from @NinaSholz does just fine.  But if you find several places where it could help, it might be worth looking into something like that.

Comment: i am really amazed how ramda works (if i ever understand how it works ...).

Comment: @NinaScholz: I've seen enough of your posts that I'm pretty sure you have a good idea how it does!  Obviously the above could be reworked according the the composition law of functors, but I like just how explicit this is.  I'm sure this code is significantly less performant than your version, but for many cases -- dare I say most? -- that difference wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it thru `_.groupBy`:

```
const res = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy('date')
    .mapValues(dateObj => _.chain(dateObj)
        .groupBy('id')
        .mapValues(idObj => ({ amount: _.sumBy(idObj, 'amount') }))
        .value()
     )
     .value();
```